# Htmlbox 'unwrap' function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In reference to [this](http://remiya.com/htmlbox/files/demo/4.0/htmlbox.full.js) plugin:.

It doesn't currently have a `unwrap` function, but it does have a "wrap" one:

```
this.wrap_tags = function(start,end){
   var sel = get_selection(); 
   if(undefined===sel){sel="";}
   if(undefined===end){end="";}
   insert_text(start+sel+end,start.length,end.length);
};
```

It doesn't use jQuery's wrap(); function - perhaps due to x-browser compatibility...? Anyway, this wrap method is called in a command like so:

```
else if(cmd==="bold"){
           this.wrap_tags("&lt;b>","&lt;/b>");
       }
```

I want to create a function to unwrap the tags on SELECTED TEXT.

Please refer to the JavaScript link above for further details.